# React Native how to change the focus automatically to the next TextInput?

Tags: react-native

I would love to make a bank card number input function .
Here's the idea , when the user complete an input box ,it will focus on the next input box automatically.
Like the picture before :
[image]

**The TextInput component(AutoTextInput):**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'
import colors from '../config/colors';
import AppText from './AppText/AppText';

function AutoTextInput(
    {input_width="100%",
    input_limit,
    input_maxLength =16,
    input_keyboardType ='numeric',
    title,
    ...ortherProps}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container,{width:input_width}}>
            <AppText style={styles.title}>{title}</AppText>
            <TextInput 
             style={styles.input_text}
             maxLength = {input_maxLength}
             keyboardType ={input_keyboardType}
             {...ortherProps}

            />
        </View>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container : {
       flexDirection : 'column',
   } ,
   input_text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color : colors.medium,
    borderColor : colors.primary,
    borderWidth :0.5,
    padding :10,
    borderRadius :5,
    textAlign :'center',
    
 
},
title : {
    fontWeight : 'bold',
},
})
export default AutoTextInput;
```

**The Screen I use this component :**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native'
import AppText from './AppText/AppText';
import AutoTextInput from './AutoTextInput';


function Visa({title}) {
    const [value,setValue] = useState("");
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
         <AppText>Card Number</AppText>
        <View style={styles.card_num_container}>
        <AutoTextInput
          input_maxLength ={4}
          input_width="23%"
          onChangeText={(text)=>setValue(text)}
          placeholder ="0000"
          />
          <AutoTextInput
          input_maxLength ={4}
          input_width="23%"
          onChangeText={(text)=>setValue(text)}
          placeholder ="0000"
          
          />
            <AutoTextInput
          input_maxLength ={4}
          input_width="23%"
          onChangeText={(text)=>setValue(text)}
          placeholder ="0000"
          />
            <AutoTextInput
          input_maxLength ={4}
          input_width="23%"
          onChangeText={(text)=>setValue(text)}
          placeholder ="0000"
          />
        </View>
         

         
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container : {
       width :"100%",
       height :"100%",
       marginTop : 25,
       flexDirection : 'column',
   } ,
   card_num_container :{
       flexDirection : 'row',
       width : "100%",
       justifyContent : 'space-around',
   },

})
export default Visa;
```

I have no idea how to make it automatically focus on the next input box ..Anyone can help ?
Thanks sooo much !

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of ref like this

```
const refs = React.useRef([])
```

Then pass those refs to the custom text input component then when the user submits 4 number on the input box focus the next input like this

```
<AutoTextInput
      input_maxLength ={4}
      input_width="23%"
      onChangeText={(text)=>setValue(text)}
      placeholder ="0000"
      forwardedRef={refs[0]}
      onSubmitEditing={() => refs[0 + 1].current.focus()} 
      forwardRef={refs[index]}/>
```

Inside AutoTextInput

```
<TextInput 
      style={styles.input_text}
      ref={this.props.forwardedRef}
      maxLength = {input_maxLength}
      keyboardType ={input_keyboardType}
      onSubmitEditing={this.props.onSubmitEditing}/>
```

Comment: Hi Ashwin , Thank you so much for your answer !! I have tried ,but in my case appeared can't find cariable : index ...  I am using Expo by the way ...Could you please take a look if it works on yours ? Thanks again !!

Comment: Create an array of TextInput. Index variable is just the index of the text input.

Comment: Hi Ashwin Mothilal , Thank you so much for your advise . I have tried again ,but still not working .. I am actually new in React Native ,therefore ,I am not sure ,What i have added is right or not ? Therefore ,I added it at the above comment that you have left .Could you please take a look of it ? If there 's a problem ,you can edit it also .Thank you so much again,had added :<TextInput
           style={styles.input_text}
           onChangeText={(text)=>{
            let value = value;
            value[i] =text;}}
           onSubmitEditing = {this.props.onSubmitEditing}
           />